# How to find the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[A|b]$ of a multivariate normal pair $(A,B)\sim \mathcal{N}$?

Tags: conditional-expectation, multinomial-distribution

Suppose that $A,B$ are random Euclidean vectors and $(A,B)$ follows a multivariate normal distribution
$$\mathcal{N}\left(\begin{bmatrix}E\\ F\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}P & Q\\ R & S\end{bmatrix}\right)$$
how can we find the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[A|b]$

Comment: You can find the formula here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions

Comment: @W.Volante Hey, are you aware of any good books that treat the derivations? Thanks

Comment: There is a reference on the Wikipedia page for this particular result.